# OnClick event to change cell background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Link to **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpumw94/2/)**

I'm having the need to change the cell's background color everytime the user click on it, but I can't get it to work!

This is my script :

```
$( function() {
    $('.tk099 td').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("red-cell");
    } );
} );
```

in which `tk099` is the table's class, and I don't want any `td` tag which has a class be affected by the event. Is this possible? Thanks alot!

Comment: Your jQuery is fine (although you don't need the last two `;`). The problem lies in your CSS specificity.

Comment: You can avoid this event firing on `td` elements with a class by using the `not` selector. `$('.tk099 td:not([class])').click(function () { ... });`

Comment: @JamieDunstan Id doesnt work? `$('.tk099 td:not([tk099tdtotal])').click( function() {`

Comment: @hoangnnm - The selector is literally as I've given it with the word `class` in it and it translates to any `td` element with a `class` attribute. If you want to exclude elements with a named class, you could do this: `$('.tk099 td:not([class="tk099tdtotal"])').click(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector `.tk099 td` takes presidence over `.red-cell` because:

- It is more specific
- It is declared later than `.red-cell` (and CSS **cascades**)

Declare `.red-cell` later on and make it just as specific/more specific:

```
.tk099 td {
    background-color:#EEEEEE; 
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    border-left:1px solid #CCC;    
}  

td.red-cell {
   background: #F00; /* Or some other color */
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpumw94/3/)

Comment: Perfect! I'm very new to this. Sorry if I keep asking silly questions !

Comment: Don't apologize. Everybody has questions at some point. Glad to have helped. FWIW I don't find this question silly.

Answer (score 2):

change css to and should be declared at the after the default css

```
td.red-cell {
   background: #F00; /* Or some other color */
}
```